# How to get all tables from text file with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have text file with such structure:

```
Some data  
====================================================================  
   1  !V09            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   2  !Vk10           !   -0.582  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   3  !V11            !   -0.591  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd 
   4  !V12            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   

Some data  
====================================================================  
   1  !V09            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   2  !Vk10           !   -0.582  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
...
```

How to get content from all table? One table per regex match.
**Updated**
In sum, I need such data in matches:

```
   1  !V09            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   2  !Vk10           !   -0.582  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   3  !V11            !   -0.591  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd 
   4  !V12            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   

   1  !V09            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
   2  !Vk10           !   -0.582  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd   
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like fixed-width columns. If there aren't any spaces within your data, use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v%3Dvs.71%29.aspx) to split on whitespace. If there are spaces, pull out substrings using [`String.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v%3Dvs.71%29.aspx) and trim whitespace with [`String.RTrim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.rtrim%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Please don't use a regex here. That would be overkill.

Comment: @Dublicator Updated answer. Please tag your question with the language in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have fixed fields and split accepts a regex delimeter, you could write it as:

delimeter regex = `/^\s*\d\s*!|!/`

**Edit**:   `/^\s*\d\s*!|[! ]+/` will split out like this
    `''    'V09'    '-0.544'    'V'    '-0.900-'    '-0.250'    'V'    'gd'`
Where the first field (array item) is a throw-away.

If fixed, you could write a really verbose regex:
 (based on a sample line)
   1  !V09            !   -0.544  V   !   -0.900-   -0.250  V   ! gd

`/^\s*\d+\s*!\s*(\S*)\s*!\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*!\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*!\s*(\S*)\s*$/`

Comment: That regex is incomprehensible.  If they're fixed width fields, why not just parse out each field based on the width?

Comment: I edited the regex delimeter for split to do just about the same thing as that ugly regex. Sometimes its easier to define it in those terms. I didn't say fixed width fields, I said fixed fields. He does seem to to want to split on subfields, between !'s. The regex validates (in a general way), trims and captures the field position data but not in a columnar sense. And split requires sub-processing to do that.